# Flow type and DOM objects

Tags: javascript, dom, gulp, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I'm trying to use flowtype to check some files.

Unfortunately I cannot get it to work with dom objects:

I have this code

```
this.canvasContext = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
```

..which returns this error:

```
src/CanvasManager.js:43
 43:         this.canvasContext = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `getContext`. Function cannot be called on
 43:         this.canvasContext = this.canvas.getContext('2d');


                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ HTMLCanvasElement
```

So basically flow recognizes the `HTMLCanvasElement`, but seems not to know that it has a `getContext` method.

Am I missing something?
If not, is there any way to extend the DOM definitions?

Creating my own definition of `HTMLCanvasElement` will result in name mismatch:

```
src/PlayingField.js:23
 23:     constructor(gameController: GameController, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ HTMLCanvasElement. This type is incompatible with
 23:     constructor(gameController: GameController, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ HTMLCanvasElement
```

Comment: There error message is not complete: "Function cannot be called on" ... what does it say?

Comment: the message is complete but it's cumbersome:- it's just split in different lines

`call of method \`getContext\`. Function cannot be called on HTMLCanvasElement`

Answer (score 2):

Seems this was a bug that [should be fixed](https://github.com/facebook/flow/commit/b568c79543d9ed162b83c1405181958fb8809f85) since v0.18.1.

Comment: I tried to update - the error is still there in 0.19:
`$ flow version
Flow, a static type checker for JavaScript, version 0.19.0`

Comment: Strange. The declaration is [right there](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/dom.js#L692), in the core library source. With 0.19 you can provide your own declaration, which will override the core library. See the sections on declaration files in the [0.19.0 announcement blog post](http://flowtype.org/blog/2015/12/01/Version-0.19.0.html).

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Flow 0.19.

After updating to Flow 0.20, the error changed to:
```call of method `getContext`. Function cannot be called on intersection: function type(s).```

Comment: This is still a problem in version 0.22.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem in 0.22.1. For some reason, Flow isn't able to properly see that `document.createElement('canvas')` returns a type of `HTMLCanvasElement` even though this is defined as an intersection type in the included DOM definition files.

To workaround this issue, just add an if statement that checks the type of the return value of `document.createElement`. For example:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
if (!(canvas instanceof HTMLCanvasElement)) {
    throw new Error('Unable to construct HTMLCanvasElement.');
}

// Do canvas specific stuff here
```